# How to properly fetch results into an arrays and pass to curl in php

Tags: php

In table content I have three data that I want to fetch and pass into array so that I finally can pass it to curl.

Here is the code I use to get the result from databases and its working fine

```
include('pdo_db.php');
$result = $db->prepare('select * from content');
$result->execute(array());
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {           
    $cda=htmlentities($row['cda'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
```

**My question** is how do I pass the three results `($cda)` into the arrays as per this line of code

```
$params = ["<first_result>","<second_result>","<third_result>"];
```

Here is the curl request am trying to implement based on my requirements

```
$params = ["<first_result>","<second_result>","<third_result>"]; 

$ch = curl_init( "myapi/url");
$headers = array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                           
  "Authorization: " . $mycredentials)                                                                       
);  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print $output;
```

Comment: *and its working fine* Are you sure? `$cda=htmlentities($row['cda'] ... ` only overwrites  cda variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include('pdo_db.php');
$result = $db->prepare('select * from content');
$result->execute(array());
$params = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {           
    // collect data as array
    $params[] = htmlentities($row['cda'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
// then pass `$params` to cUrl
```